# Changing tintColor for button's PDF vector image

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, xcode11.1

I've added a `PDF` image as an asset to `Xcode`, I want to change the `tintColor` of the image but without any success.

I've tried to add `User Defined Runtime Attributes`, but it won't work.

Also tried to change programatically, but it won't work.

```
self.buttonBringFriend.imageView.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Xcode 11.1 Swift 5.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set image color, use the below method:

```
extension UIImageView {

    func setImageColor(color: UIColor) {
            let templateImage = self.image?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
            self.image = templateImage
            self.tintColor = color
        }

    }
```

How to use:-

```
self.buttonBringFriend.imageView.setImageColor(color: .white)
```

Comment: Works great, but when I click the image and it become highlighted, the color change back to the original color.

Comment: @YossiTsafar On highlight, set the same image using this method.  There are two ways of doing this: 1 )Subclass your button and call this method when highlighted. 2) Set the same highlighted image

Comment: tried that already, but it's not working. Do I call self.highlightedImage?

Comment: @YossiTsafar, Yes, in the `setImageColor ` method, write this line: `self. highlightedImage = templateImage`

Comment: After setting the color, try to add this line: `buttonBringFriend.imageView?.highlightedImage = buttonBringFriend.imageView?.image`

Answer (score 7):

Have you set `Render As: Template Image` in the Asset properties?

[image]